# After retrying, task marked success in Airflow but it should marked failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. I am running a DAG and I have set retries to 5. My expectation is that, If a task got failed, it will retry 5 times and if it doesn't get pass it will mark it as failed but contrary to that, the task marked as success and triggered the upstream task, despite it has not done all the updates required in that particular task to get complete. Am I missing any required parameter? Thanks.

Note- I am using dataproc cluster and updating records in BQ table and it has limitation of 1500 updates/table/day. That limit got exceeded, but airflow didn't bother to mark it failed, rather it has triggered upstream task. Any fix which we can use? so that the task would have failed even if there is limit/quota exceed issue?

issue- "write to table failed: Reason: 403 limit error due to append/update limit exceeded"- After this, It started running the other codes available. But how can I tell Airflow that it's an error and should stop the task?

```py
writing_to_bq(df=ent1, table, retry_number=3) 

def writing_to_bq(df,table,retry):  
    for _ in range(retry+1):  
       try:  
         df.to_gbq(table,if_exists=“append")

         break
       except
          Exception as e:

    log.info("Trying again”)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you set args globally (for all your tasks) or only in the task, it should work as expected :

```py
dag_default_args={
    'owner' : 'Airflow',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    ...
}

with airflow.DAG(
        "your_dag_id",
        default_args=dag_default_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
....
```

In this example, I used a `retry_delay` to 2 minutes.

After discussed together, you indicated the BigQueryInsertJobOperator operator doesn't mark the task as failed if you receive a 403 status for a quota limit exceeded.

You can also use a `PythonOperator` with `Python` `BigQuery` client, in this case normally the client will throw an error for a 403 status. If it's not the case, you can have more flexibility to apply logic based on the result :

```py
def execute_bq_query():
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    client = bigquery.Client()

    QUERY = 'SELECT ....'

    query_job = client.query(QUERY) 
    rows = query_job.result()

PythonOperator(
    task_id="task_id",
    python_callable=execute_bq_query
)
```

Comment: but the issue is that, I am updating records in BQ table and it has limitation of 1500 updates/table/day. That limit got exceeded, but airflow didn't bother to mark it failed, rather it has triggered upstream task. Any fix which we can use? so that the task would have failed even if there is limit/quota exceed issue?

Comment: Can you simulate a real error in your task and check the behaviour of the retry please in order to be sure the retry works as expected ? Then we will check why the quota limit doesn't resulting to an error. For example, you can simulate an error with a bad syntax in your sql query.

Comment: Yes, for all other, retries is working as expected but for the quota, It didn't fail.

Comment: If you execute your query directly in the `BigQuery` console, have you an error ?

Comment: Can't check that. Actually, our pipeline got failed many times, that's why it exceeds the quota limit as we re-ran it couple of times.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please in order to check the operator you used ? Normally the Airflow operator use the `BigQuery` api, that means the api doesn't returns an error in this case.

Comment: Hey, you are correct. In the log, it is not coming as error- It is coming like this-INFO- Written to BQ table failed due to : Reason: 403 quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table. How can i tell Airflow that it's an error and should stop the task and mark it as failed? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am thinking sort of reading the response coming from BQ API and check if 403 quota exceed present in it. I will write 1 assert to fail the task on top of that. what are your thoughts on it? I am not sure how to read response, need to check for the code.

Comment: Yes instead of using the native `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`, you can use a `PythonOperator` with `Python` client. Get the return status or with a `try catch` on response. If you have an error or the 403 status, you can throw an exception, it will break the task and mark it as failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251393/discussion-between-a-gupta-and-mazlum-tosun).

Comment: Can you add one more thing in your answer? We can handle exception and write assert(using some flag if 'passed' or 'failed') to forcefully throw an error, that can also solve our purpose right?